# JAVA PDFBox Embed EPS, converted to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, embed, pdfbox, eps

I'm currently working with PDFBox in Java through Eclipse (with PDFBox as build path JAR).

I want to embed a EPS logo file into the PDF I want to create.

I read we cannot directly embed .eps files so I converted it to PDF beforehand. Now the problem is to embed a PDF into the existing PDF:

```
String fileUrl="BlankPage.pdf";
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage homePage = new PDPage();
homePage.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
document.addPage(homePage);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, homePage);
...
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("images/logotype.pdf");
```

The question, is How to embed the **doc** variable into **contentStream** ?

Thanks